# Inner constructor of parametric type

Tags: julia

I am a bit confused about the type annotations in inner constructor of parametric type.

Are there any difference in the following 4 approaches, in terms of JIT inference efficiency, and runtime efficiency?

```
immutable MyType{T}
    x::T
    MyType{T}(x::T) = new{T}(x + x)
end

immutable MyType{T}
    x::T
    MyType(x::T) = new{T}(x + x)
end

immutable MyType{T}
    x::T
    MyType(x::T) = new(x + x)
end

immutable MyType{T}
    x::T
    MyType{T}(x::T) = new(x + x)
end
```

They all work for `x = MyType{Int}(1)`

Answer (score 2):

According to Jeff's answer [here](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/clarify-parametric-new/11608):

> Question 1: If the name of the type is X, and the constructor has the
>   form function X{...}(...) then the contents of the curly braces right
>   after the X are passed to new.
>
> Question 2: To make an instance, type parameters must have definite
>   values, so new(...) is always equivalent to some new{...}(...). They
>   will lower to the exact same thing.

they're exact the same thing. Your last example is a canonical pattern:

```
struct MyType{T}
    x::T
    MyType{T}(x::T) = new(x + x)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I declared `MyType` using the above 4 approaches:

```
immutable MyType1{T}
    x::T
    MyType1{T}(x::T) = new{T}(x + x)
end
immutable MyType2{T}
    x::T
    MyType2(x::T) = new{T}(x + x)
end
immutable MyType3{T}
    x::T
    MyType3{T}(x::T) = new(x + x)
end
immutable MyType4{T}
    x::T
    MyType4(x::T) = new(x + x)
end
```

then printed their LLVM bytecode: `code_llvm(MyType1{Int},Int)` and compared the outputs, they are exactly the same, so I think **there are no difference between 4 approaches.**