# Parametric composite type inner constructors in Julia: Why is `where {T}` necessary?

Tags: julia

Why does this raise `LoadError: UndefVarError: T not defined`:

```
struct Point{T}
    x::T
    y::T
    Point{T}(x,y) = new(x,y)
end
```

while this works fine:

```
struct Point{T}
    x::T
    y::T
    Point{T}(x,y) where {T} = new(x,y)
end
```

?

It seems that once upon a time they were both fine: [Inner constructor of parametric type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33573478/inner-constructor-of-parametric-type)

EDIT: To clarify, I would have expected the fact that we are within the `struct Point{T}` block to have made it clear what `T` refers to even in the first case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without `where` clause `T` is inherited from the global scope (which is kind of surprising, but this is how it works):

```
julia> T = String
String

julia> struct Point{T}
           x::T
           y::T
           Point{T}(x,y) = new(x,y)
       end

julia> Point{String}("b","a")
Point{String}("b", "a")

julia> Point{String}(SubString("b",1,1),SubString("a",1,1))
Point{String}("b", "a")

julia> Point{Int}(1, 2)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching Point{Int64}(::Int64, ::Int64)

julia> Point{String}(1, 2)
ERROR: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type Int64 to an object of type String
```

**EDIT**

The short answer, given the comments on Discourse, is that the reason for this is that `T` of `struct` is not known at the moment an inner constructor is called.

Comment: I find this more than a bit surprising and confusing, especially given the following is just fine:
```
T = String

struct Point{T}
    x::T
    y::T
end

Point{Int64}(1,2)
```
So the `T` in the inner constructor declaration comes from the global scope, but the `T` for the `struct` does not, even though the former is within the latter. Is that correct?

Comment: Watch https://discourse.julialang.org/t/parametric-inner-constructor-inherits-parameter-from-global-scope/22296 so we will see what other people think (whether it is surprising or not - maybe there is some deeper reason behind it). In general the parameter in `struct` definition is detached from the parameter in an inner constructor (that is why you can change it using `where`), but maybe - as you have said - it should be inherited by default from the `struct` as an outer scope.

Comment: I don't want T to be a string!! How do I make it a type parameter?